# Getting statistics from Google DV360 campaign via API

Tags: google-api, dv360

I'm trying to use google API to get reports on campaigns/ads that are created in Display & Video 360.

Fetching information about them requires `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/display-video` scope for my access token. However, it looks like getting reports is only possible through creating/running [queries](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/queries), which are part of Double Click Bid Manager, so I need to additionally enable this API and request `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager` scope.

Is my understanding correct? It seems strange because I can view reports in DV360 web interface.